# How do I add a popup menu to a C# Console Application like F7 in Windows command prompt?

Tags: c#, console-application

As the subject explains, when you hit **F7** in a **Windows command prompt** a popup is shown where you can select a list of commands you already executed:

Selection is done via UP/DOWN arrow and the popup disappear only after selecting an option or pressing the Esc key.
How can I implement that in a Console Application written in C#?

The idea is to bind it to an Fkey and use it as a quick menu.

Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: Run some commands before pressing F7, like `ipconfig` or `ping localhost`

Comment: It's a feature of the shell - it's not something a user-application can implement, sorry.

Comment: Are you asking how to implement your own popup *at a command-line prompt* (i.e. without an application running), or how you can render a box in the console *after* your application has loaded?

Comment: If it's the latter then use a .NET port of `curses`/`ncurses` like https://github.com/MV10/dotnet-curses

Comment: @Dai: exactly that, how to implement a popup in my own Console Application

Comment: "how to implement a popup in my own Console Application" - **I just told you** gah

Comment: @Dai: it seems to me that I've to rewrite my whole application using dotnet-curses, could you please provide an example of a popup menu done with that library?